# How do I merge and cleanup up multiple tags in one?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm racking my brain and cannot get this issue resolved using XSL in an elegant manner. I have an XML element with nested tags creating a headline. For display purposes, this is fine. But when exporting to a vendor for online publishing it causes a problem.

See the element:

```
<headline>
  <ln id="U20777523148AQE">FOOD PARCEL</ln>
  <ln id="U20777523148kHH">LOOTING</ln>
  <ln id="U20777523148buE">HITS THE POOR</ln>
</headline>
```

The ideal solution should end up like:

```
<headline>
  <ln>FOOD PARCEL LOOTING HITS THE POOR</ln>
</headline>
```

Of course, the number of lines (ln) could also differ. From a single line to multiples as demonstrated in the example. Some assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here's an example of the not-so-great idea that I had.

```
<headline>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[1]/text()"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[2]/text()"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[3]/text()"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[4]/text()"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[5]/text()"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</headline>
```

Some more background - see the current XSL in which the transformation is used.

```
<doc>
    <story>
        <grouphead>
            <overhead>
                <ln>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/overhead/ln/text()"/>
                </ln>
            </overhead>
            <headline>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[1]/text()"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[2]/text()"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[3]/text()"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[4]/text()"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/headline/ln[5]/text()"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </headline>
            <subhead>
                <ln>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/doc/story/grouphead[1]/subhead/ln/text()"/>
                </ln>
            </subhead>
        </grouphead>
        <text>
            <byline>
                <author>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/doc/story/text/byline/author/name/text()"/>
                    </name>
                    <description>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/doc/story/text/byline/author/description/text()"/>
                    </description>
                </author>
            </byline>
        </text>
    </story>
</doc>
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this? Post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Also state if your processor supports XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your processors supports XSLT 2.0 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="headline">
      <xsl:copy>
          <ln><xsl:value-of select="ln"/></ln>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If it only supports XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="headline">
    <xsl:copy>
      <ln>
        <xsl:for-each select="ln">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"> <!-- Add space if not last element -->
              <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ln>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDiMBZ

Comment: I'm using version 1.0 for the transformation of the file.

Comment: Counting the lines repeatedly in every iteration of `xsl:for-each` is inefficient. You can simply use `test="position()!=last()">`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for your comment. Learning more everyday! Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone and for sure, Sebastien. The xslt 1.0 solution as noted above works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal can easily be achieved by getting the *string-value* of `headline`,

> The [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of an element node is the concatenation of the
>   [string-values](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of all text node [descendants](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-descendants) of the element
>   node in document order.

and then cleaning up whitespace via [normalize-space()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space).

### XSLT, all versions

This XSLT,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="headline">
    <xsl:copy>
      <ln>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
      </ln>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input XML, yields this output XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<headline>
  <ln>FOOD PARCEL LOOTING HITS THE POOR</ln>
</headline>
```

as requested.

---

<sup>**Note:** This approach will work even if there is further text outside of `ln` (e.g. commas or other punctuation); this technique is commonly used for mixed-content elements in the role of `headline`.  On the other hand, ***it will not introduce spacing between `ln` elements if none exists originally.***    If you wish whitespace to be introduced between `ln` elements regardless of whether it exists in the source XML, see [Sebastien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446896/290085).  [Thanks, @michael.hor257k, for [pointing out this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446474/how-do-i-merge-and-cleanup-up-multiple-tags-in-one/61447106#comment108697741_61447106).]</sup>

Comment: I am not sure it's good practice to rely on the input being indented.

Comment: For sure. It's currently just for testing purposes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k:  I added a note regarding the helpful point you made.  Thank you!